# drawRect: crash by big rect after zomming

Tags: objective-c, quartz-core

My UIView structure:
I have a `"master"` UIView (actually `UIScrollView`, but it's only purpose scrolling per pagination).
As a subView on this `"master"` I have my `"pageView"` (subclass of `UIScrollView`). This `UIScrollView` can have any content (e.g. a UIImageView).
The `"master"` has another subView: `PaintView` (subclass of UIView). With this view, I track the finger movements and draw it.

The structure looks like this:

```
[master.view addSubview: pageView];
[master.view addSubview: paintView];
```

I know when the user zooms in (pageView is responsible for this) and over delegate/method calls I change the frame of `paintView` according to the zoom change, during the zoom action.
After zooming `(scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale)` I call a custom redraw method of paintView.

Redraw method and drawRect:

```
-(void)redrawForScale:(float)scale {
    for (UIBezierPath *path in _pathArray) {
        //TransformMakeScale...
    }
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
} 

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    for (UIBezierPath *path in _pathArray) {
        [path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    } 
}
```

**The problem**:
When I zoom-in, I receive a memory warning and the app crashes.

In the Allocations profiler I can see that the app own a lot of memory, but I can't see why.
When I don't call `'setNeedDisplay'` after my `'redrawForScale'` method the app isn't crashing.

When I log the rect in drawRect I see values like this: {{0, 0.299316}, {4688, 6630}}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (re)drawing such a huge CGRect (correct me if this is wrong).
The solution for me is to avoid calling a custom drawRect method. In some stackoverflow answers (and I think somewhere in the Appls docs) it was mentioned that a custom `drawRect:` will reduce the performance (because iOS can't do some magic on a custom drawRect method).

My solution:
Using a `CAShapeLayer`. For every UIBezierPath I create a CAShapeLayer instance, add the UIBezierPath to the `path` attribute of the layer and add the layer as a sublayer to my view.

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] initWithLayer:self.layer];
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10.0;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.path = myBezierPath.CGPath;
[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

With this solution I don't need to implement drawRect. So the App won't crash, even with a big maximumZoomScale.

After changing the UIBezierPath (translate, scale, change color) I need to set the changed bezierPath to the shapeLayer again (set the `path` attribute of shapeLayer again).